# TextStyle in js-joda is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, js-joda

I imported the classes this way:

```
const { LocalDate, TextStyle } = require('js-joda');
console.log(TextStyle);
```

**Output:**

```
undefined
```

I would like to use it as follows:

```
const dateTime = LocalDate.now()
dateTime.dayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW_STANDALONE);
```

The `LocalDate` class works as supposed to.
Why TextStyle is **undefined** ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this question is still open/valid since it has been asked a while ago, but with version >=1.6.0, the `TextStyle` class should also be exported and the above code should work

Regards, Pattrick